# Django rest framework uploading multiple files

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

Is there a way to handle multiple file uploading? It seems that even the client is sending multiple files (thourgh a web browser), the MultiPartParser will only select the first file.

Comment: DRF uses django's `MultiPartParser` so it definitely handles multiple files. Can you show your code?

Comment: @mariodev, I dont know how to write the serializer. There are only FileField and ImageField, which will only handle single file.

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is an old question, but I just spent some time banging my head against this.  The issue is that Django's `MultiPartParser`, which DRF uses, returns `files` as a `MultiValueDict`.  When DRF then then adds the files back to the data that is passed to the serializer, it does so using `.update()` on the data (which is an `OrderedDict`) in `request.Request._load_data_and_files()`.  The result is that if multiple files are uploaded with the same key, only the last one survives [1] and makes it as far as the serializer.

Django's documentation recommends over-riding the `.post()` method in the `FormView` if using a form [2].  An alternative is to subclass the parser, and call `dict()` on the `files` `MultiValueDict` before returning it, so that lists are returned instead of being reduced to their last value.  I'm using the second option, as I'm subclassing the parser already anyway.

[1] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/utils/datastructures/

[2] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to validate multiple uploaded files, then you will have to write your own serializer for that. There is a [serializers.ListField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield) for validating lists of objects. I haven't tried this, but I believe you could implement a simple serializer like this:

```
class FileListSerializer ( serializers.Serializer ) :

    files = serializers.ListField(
                child=serializers.FileField( max_length=100000,
                                             allow_empty_file=False,
                                             use_url=False )
            )
```

Then probably you could validate the files by calling the serializer from the view:

```
files = list( request.FILES.values() )
files_serializer = FileListSerializer( data={"files": files} )
if not file_serializer.is_valid() :
    # handle error
    ...
```

Comment: This is not working... I have tried it but the files are lost in field validations.

Answer (score 2):

You may access the file list through `request.FILES.getlist('<your_payload_files_key>')`.

I got the answer from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37280575/510577).

Comment: Yup this is how I handle it in normal django forms - simple!