# Uploading multiples image with Django Rest Framework in a single POST array?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

Good day everyone, I have a problem using DRF for getting multiples images in a single Post with an array.

I have read a lot about this topic, the most common solution is to encode64 the string, but is not an approach that I want because take a lot of resource that we don't have.

The other one, is the most common that DRF use, to request method to Parse the header in the content type. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#how-the-parser-is-determined
But if I'm correct, this use a multipart/form-data way to do it.

The really one that I want, is a way to do it just receiving the data in a Json Array, this is by using a mobile app build in appcelerator where the user sends an array of images.

I would be glad if someone answer me if at least is possible, because all the information that I have found only point to multipart/form-data.

By the way, is possible to upload a single file, but not multiples, I have done it with this:

ukeys = request.FILES['fotos']

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The really one that I want, is a way to do it just receiving the data in a Json Array, this is by using a mobile app build in appcelerator where the user sends an array of images.

You'll want to inspect the underlying request and figure out *exactly* what's actually being sent on the wire. JSON doesn't support a file primitive, so the "array of images" is likely to actually be an array of strings with some kind of encoding.

> request.FILES['fotos']

For multiple values, use `request.FILES.getlist('fotos')`.

Comment: When I receive a single file it returns the name of the file encode in unicode: u' foto1.jpg But when I use getlist it only returns me an empty array. []

Update: I tried to print ukeys that is the variable of the ukeys = request.FILES.getlist('fotos'), and only give me an empty array, but if a print the request.Files, it give me the values encode in unicode, and I can even use a For to get the image name. 


Now the only problem that I have is how the application sends me the "array of images"